# Search input is causing the rest of my search functionality to fail (rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, search

I am building a search page within my rails app and have come into a situation.  In my search inputs I am trying to search for three things. The name, if they are offer higher service, and if they have urgent care.  What I am trying to do is with the name search input, i'm am trying to have a list of all of the names so that a user can select one of them without having to type in the actual name. (after which it allows the user to view the profile of each clinic)

The problem that I am getting is if I try to list all of the names in the search input, it cancels out the other two search inputs and they don't work.

My search page looks like this

```
= f.input :higher, as: :boolean, wrapper: :checkbox_wrapper, input_html: {class: 'ace-switch ace-switch-7'}, hint: '', label: "higher service?"

= f.input :urgent, as: :boolean, wrapper: :checkbox_wrapper, input_html: {class: 'ace-switch ace-switch-7'}, hint: '', label: "Urgent Care"

= f.input :name, collection: Location.all.sort_by { |c| [c] }.collect{|c| [c.name]}, input_html: {class: 'chzn-select', data: {'placeholder' => 'Select Locations'}, multiple: true}, label_method: :first, value_method: :last, label: "Location Name", required: false
```

It is the third input that is causing me a problem. 
Now if i just set it as:  `= f.input :name, label: "Location Name"` The other two options work.  I just rather not go down that road because you have to know the specific name of the location word for word.

Now in my controller

```
 def index
   @locations = @locations.where.not(priority: nil)
   @lc = AdminLocationCollection.from_params(@locations,  location_collection_params)

  binding.pry
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.csv { send_data(@lc.to_csv, type: :csv) }
  end
end

def search
  @lc = AdminLocationCollection.from_params(@locations, search_params)
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.csv { send_data(@lc.to_csv, type: :csv) }
  end
```

and finally I have a collection

```
def filter_by_params(v)
v = v.where(name: @name) if @name.present?
end
```

Now I kept the `binding.pry` in my controller because that is where I believe the problem is.  If I am to leave the name input to just `= f.input, :name` and then search for the `urgent care` option. When the console breaks, if I type in `@lc.name.present?` my output becomes `false`. this is good, it allows everything to work.

However if instead I have the longer search option and try everything else, my output becomes `true`.

I don't know why this is happening, and ultimately this is my question. I need the console output to be `false` when i'm searching for the other options.  How can I keep my name search options open to being able to list all of them in the search params, without the `:name` search functionality over-ride the others?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could replace the name search with something that's more flexible and doesn't require knowing the exact name word for word.

```
v = v.where("lower_case(name) LIKE ?", "%#{@name.downcase}%")
```

This will do a search for partial names and also doesn't worry about case.

Comment: Hm...I looked into going down that path, however it's not recognizing `lower_case` I'm getting the undefined method error.

Comment: The whole string "lower_case(name) LIKE ?" is being passed as a SQL command, so you shouldn't be getting any Ruby undefined method.  Did you put the quotation marks around it?

Comment: Oh my goodness, I'm so sorry. The error that It was giving me was `downcase` not `lower_case`.   The sql command was working fine, it was the regex part.

Comment: Ah, right... I'm not assigning `@name` because I assumed it's assigned elsewhere in your model but it looks like it's nil.  Where have you got this line, in `filter_by_params` ?  That's a controller method?  Are you initializing `@name` somewhere?

Comment: So the `filter_by_params` is created through a collection that is called `AdminLocationCollection` which is referenced in the `search method` in the controller.   The `name` is found in the locations table associated with the location model.  It also is part of the `permitted params` within the actual locations_controller.

Comment: So in place of the instance variable `@name` we should be using the `permitted_params[:name]`  Since you're passing the params into the `from_params` method you can pass the name param, in turn, to the `filter_by_params` method.

Comment: Hey, thank you so much for your patience and good help, I greatly do appreciate it!